# ImportError: cannot import name 'is_directory'

Tags: parsing, layout

I've been trying to read pdf pages as an image, for extraction purposes.

I found that layoutparser serves this purpose by identifying blocks of text. However, when I try to Create a Detectron2-based Layout Detection Model, I encounter the following:

```
import layoutparser as lp
model = lp.Detectron2LayoutModel( config_path ='lp://PubLayNet/mask_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x/config',
                             extra_config=["MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST", 0.65],
                             label_map={0: "Text", 1: "Title", 2: "List", 3:"Table", 4:"Figure"})
```

Error: [enter image description here][1]

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent 

call last)
<ipython-input-16-eab7187a31c8> in <module>()
      1 import layoutparser as lp
----> 2 model = lp.Detectron2LayoutModel( config_path ='lp://PubLayNet/mask_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x/config',
      3                                  extra_config=["MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST", 0.65],
      4                                  label_map={0: "Text", 1: "Title", 2: "List", 3:"Table", 4:"Figure"})
      5 layout = model.detect(image) # You need to load the image somewhere else, e.g., image = cv2.imread(...)

31 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py in <module>()
     35 from . import Image
     36 from ._deprecate import deprecate
---> 37 from ._util import is_directory, is_path
     38 
     39 

ImportError: cannot import name 'is_directory' from 'PIL._util' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/_util.py)
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried with pillow version <=6.2.2. It worked for me.

Comment: The current version of detectron2 (0.6) needs a higher version. Pillow 9.5 works.

Answer (score 1):

You might have installed a higher version of pillow. Try the following command to downgrade the pillow package. You should **install pillow version less than or equal to 6.2.2.**

```
pip install --upgrade pillow==6.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use wordcloud library in databricks and faced this issue twice. both were related to the version of DBR that I was using. the first time the wordcloud library was behind the databricks DBR version and a downgrade to DBR version 9.1 fixed the issue. and the second time, it seems that workcloud was updated and the latest LTS 14.3 fixed the issue.

to sum up, try to find a version or package incompatibility thingy in your dependencies or environment.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply install detectron2 from github :

```
!pip install 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git@v0.4#egg=detectron2'
```